# LINQ Deffered Execution Subtlety

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

All, I have recently localised the entire aplication and I am faced with the following problem;I have the following LINQ query in my application

```
var ccsum = from a in dtSumGL2.AsEnumerable()
    group Math.Abs(a.Field<double>(strpcPSPassBegCost)) by new 
    {
       BaseCC = a.Field<string>(strpcBaseCC)
    }
       into g
       select new
       {
          g.Key.BaseCC,
          PSPassBegCost = g.Sum()
       };
```

This is creating a new object `ccsum` which we use to create a `DataTable` and subsequently populate an SQL Server database.

The problem is that each of the new items being created in the `DataTable` with column names `BaseCC` and `PSPassBegCost`, but these names do not matched the German version of these names. Now for my question: **is there a way to do something like:**

```
var ccsum = from a in dtSumGL2.AsEnumerable()
    group Math.Abs(a.Field<double>(strpcPSPassBegCost)) by new 
    {
       BaseCC = a.Field<string>(strpcBaseCC)
    }
       into g
       select new
       {
          g.Key.BaseCC as Resources.BaseCC,
          PSPassBegCost = g.Sum() as Resources.PSPassBegCost 
       };
```

**so that I can name the tables according to their localised names?**

---

Edit. The code that retrieve a `DataTable` from `ccsum` is

```
fooDt = Utils.LINQToDataTable(ccsum);
```

and

```
public static DataTable LINQToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> varlist)
{

    DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
    PropertyInfo[] oProps = null;
    if (varlist == null) 
    return dtReturn;

    foreach (T rec in varlist)
    {
        // Use reflection to get property names, to create 
        // table, Only first time, others will follow.
        if (oProps == null)
        {
            oProps = ((Type)rec.GetType()).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
            {
                Type colType = pi.PropertyType;
                if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                {
                    colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
                dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, colType));
            }
        }

        DataRow dr = dtReturn.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
        {
            pi.GetValue(rec, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pi.GetValue(rec, null);
        }
        dtReturn.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return dtReturn;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

*Another approach might be to rename the 'columns' in the `ccsum` object as a post-processing step although the values of `sumcc` are not populated until they are requested at run-time - any other ideas?*

Comment: Localizing your table names is asking for a metric-ton of trouble, pain, and suffering.

Comment: So you're saying that the tables in your database have different column names depending on the language? That doesn't sound like a good idea to me...

Comment: Wait, you wan't your database-tables to have localized names? They why aren't you showing us the code which inserts stuff into your database? Variable-names in a LINQ-query in general has nothing to do with database-column-names, with the exception that a lot of ORM's rely on reflection of the properties to populate databases, but without knowing what ORM/insertion-code you use, there's little we can do to help.

Comment: Mapping to column names is part of the DataTable config.

Comment: bad idea and not necessary at all, if it's for some one else (who is German) being able to read, just encourage him to learn English. English is the must-learn for all programmers.

Comment: I don't see why it is such a bad idea (apart from the problem I have highlighted!). It will make the system much more user friendly to foreign users. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: @Alxandr I can add the code that take the result from the LINQ query above and converts (via reflection) to `DataTable` [and subsequently inserts into a SQL Database (that the user will load into a BI system]. But this conversion does not have any place in which to inject/change the required localised column name...

Comment: FYI your question title has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: @James I think it does. The values in the section of the LINQ query I have shown are retrieved at run-time using deferred execution, which is a potentially important consideration...

Comment: @Killercam your question is how do you dynamically map column names from a projection query - nothing to do with deferred execution (albeit it *might* be using it). Also, I am not sure I completely understand the use-case for what it is you are trying to do...are you allowing users to create custom tables from a UI?

Comment: @James Yes, here they specify there own columns names from the UI. It is a large and complex system which does some complex internal work to create table but can also parse SQL and allow users to create their own SQL (through a number of mechanisms). I take you point about the deferred execution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create class or enum which will map column indexes to some readable names:

```
public static class SumGLColumn
{
    public const int BaseCC = 0;
    public const int PSPassBegCost = 1;
}
```

And use column indexes instead of column names to query your datatable:

```
var ccsum = from a in dtSumGL2.AsEnumerable()
            group Math.Abs(a.Field<double>(SumGLColumn.PSPassBegCost)) 
                  by a.Field<string>(SumGLColumn.BaseCC) into g
            select new {
               BaseCCg = g.Key,
               PSPassBegCost = g.Sum()
            };
```

Comment: This is a great idea. I had not thought of this approach. Wouldn't we require a second `Math.Abs` on the `a.Field<string>(SumGLColumn.BaseCC)`? Also, I am still not sure how this would get around the fact that elsewhere in the code I expect the German of `BaseCC` and when I attempt to get the `DataTable` from the result of the above LINQ and put it into the SQL Table `BaseCC` will not exist... Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: +1, a nice idea - provided that the users always create their tables in the order of the LINQ query...

Comment: @Killercam well, you are grouping by string, so you just want all items which have same BaseCC value in group - it doesn't matter whether BaseCC will be in English or Chinese. Didn't get your case with saving into SQL table. Can you provide more info? BTW `DataTable` purpose is holding data. Localization should happen on UI control, so consider to localize headers only in grid, not in datatable

Comment: That was stupid of me. I was in a rush to meeting, sorry. I need to match the column that is set in another `DataTable` which has the German version of the `BaseCC` - so after I get the `Datatable` from the LINQ query I combine the two `DataTable`s, but of course the one that has come from the above query does not have the correct column name... There is a lot of code I did not write and I may have done this another way knowing that it was to go through the localisation process...

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to localize components of your system for greater human comprehension is a laudable goal, but it will give you challenges in using the the vast majority of tools and libraries: generally database tooling expects these things to be constant and ignorant of localization.

If you wish your database tables to be easier to understand, perhaps a more practical solution would be to produce localized views instead? The views could live in a `de` schema and be one-to-one translations of your tables. This would allow you to leverage a lot of the standard tooling, keeping your system in a consistent "neutral" culture internally (whatever your development culture is) and providing translations over the top of these wherever required.

I think trying to embed this kind of localization into the heart of your system is likely to not be worth the cost of working around the expectations of most developers and toolsets and you're better providing a façade.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer. Like many of us, the system I am working with has grown large and complex over time. Any introduction of a façade at this point is likely to be prohibitively expensive in terms of time to implement and involve other unforeseen problems. I don't think our approach is totally flawed at this stage all but one section of the system is running in German. The above subtlety is the only (at this stage!) area of the code that has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. In the select statement you define an anonymous type. This is not a language feature, but a compiler-feature, which means that the compiler creates a class for this type with the properties you define.

This means that the compiler must know the names at compile time. If you want something more dynamic, I recommend you to use a dictionary:

```
select new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
    { Resources.BaseCC, g.Key.BaseCC },
    { Resources.PSPassBegCost , g.Sum() }
};
```

Comment: I completed the sample, you can just replace your select statement. But I would carefully think about, if you really need it.